# Problems in finding an integral basis in a ring of algebraic ntegers

Tags: matrices, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have some problems with [this paper](http://media.wix.com/ugd/18f425_58e29a3ba780690f4b00fd9f66a5c529.pdf).

- Firstly, with theorem 3.4: I don't know if this is the original formulation in the literature, but the statement seems rather trivial to me if one considers $0$ to be an algebraic integer. Moreover there are cases where a non trivial integer doesn't even exist as in the classical example of the ring of integers of  $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ where $d \in  \Bbb Z$ and $d \neq 1 \mod 4$.
- Secondly, in the algorithm that is based on this theorem. As an example I consider the polynomial $x^4+5x+5$. The Galois group of this polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ is the cyclic group of order $4$ abd its splitting field can be represented by its companion matrix $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & -5\\1 & 0 & 0 & -5\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Since $M$ is an algebraic integer one can take as a basis of integers for the splitting field the set $B = \{M^0,M,M^2,M^3\}$.The discriminant of this basis using $\Delta = \det(\operatorname{Tr}(B_iB_j))$ equals $5^3\dot 11^2$ (as does the discriminant of the polynomial). If I apply the algorithm I find an algebraic integer with coefficients $\frac{1}{11}\left [ 1, 3, 6,1\right ]$ (the minimal polynomial is $x^4+x^3+6x^2-4x+1$). If I replace in B the second element by this element I obtain a basis whose discriminant now is $5^33^2$, so we are nowhere nearer to an integral basis, on the contrary, one bastard goes out and another comes in.
- Conclusion: We know that the discriminant of an intergral basis divides that of a basis of integers so in out case it divides both discriminants so also their $\gcd, 5^3$. If only there was a way to calculate the $\gcd$ of two bases of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a formulation which makes more sense. First, recall some terms.

1. There is the discriminant of the field $K$, given as follows: If $\alpha_i$ denotes an basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\mathbf{Z}$, then

$$\Delta_K = \Delta(\alpha_i):=\det \mathrm{Tr}(\alpha_i \alpha_j).$$

2. If $\beta_i$ are $n = [K:\mathbf{Q}]$ elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$, one can also define:

$$\Delta(\beta_i):= \det \mathrm{Tr}(\alpha_i \alpha_j).$$

3. As a special case, if $\beta \in K$ is the root of a polynomial $f(x)$ which generates $K$, and $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are the powers $1$, $\beta, \ldots , \beta^{n-1}$, then $\Delta(\beta_i)$ is the discriminant of the polynomial $f$.

The key relation is that:

$$\Delta(\beta_i) = [\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbf{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n]]^2 \cdot \Delta_K.$$

From this, one can deduce the following:

1. If $p$ divides the index of $\mathbf{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n]$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $p^2$ divides $\Delta(\beta_i)$.
2. If $p$ divides the index of $\mathbf{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n]$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then there is an algebraic integer of the form

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{p} \left(\lambda_1 \beta_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n \beta_n \right)$$

where $0 \le \lambda_i < p$ for all $i$ *and* not all of them are zero.

(This is the correct formulation of the statement you linked too --- one may insist that not all the $\lambda_i$ are zero, but this only exists if $p$ actually divides the index of the $\beta_i$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, simply dividing $\Delta(\beta_i)$ is not enough. Of course, in practice, you can try this for all the possible $p$, and if you don't find a $\gamma$ then you have an integral basis.

3. In practice, you start with an element $\beta$ and consider the set $\{1,\beta,\ldots,\beta^{n-1}\} = \{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$. But the main point is that --- if you find $\gamma$ --- you *don't* replace the power basis of $\beta$ by the power basis of $\gamma$, but rather take:

$$\{\beta'_1,\ldots,\beta'_n\} = \left\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_{n-1},\frac{1}{p} \left(\lambda_1 \beta_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n \beta_n \right)\right\}.$$

This now has smaller index and you repeat. **Edit:** More carefully, you really want your new lattice to contain the old lattice. So you want the lattice generated by all the $\beta_i$ *together* with $\gamma$. You can ensure this as follows. At least one of the $\lambda_j$ will be non-zero modulo $p$ by construction. Replacing $\gamma$ by some multiple, one can first assume that $\lambda_j \equiv 1 \mod p$, and then, subtracting a multiple of $\beta_j$, one can assume $\lambda_j = 1$. Then the larger lattice $\{\beta_i,\gamma\}$ is generated by $\gamma$ and $\beta_i$ for $i \ne j$, and so this will have smaller index. **End Edit**

In your example, let $\beta$ be a root of $x^4 + 5x + 5$. You then discover a new integral element $\gamma$, for example,  your element:

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{11} \gamma^3 + \frac{6}{11} \gamma^2 + \frac{3}{11} \gamma + \frac{1}{11},$$

which does not lie in this basis. The next step is to consider $\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\gamma\}$. That will actually be a basis in this case. In fact, I compute the trace pairing matrix to be:

$$\left( \begin{matrix} 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & -15 & -10 \\ 0 & -15 & -20 & -15 \\ -1 & -10 & -15 & -11 \end{matrix} \right),$$

which has discriminant $5^3$. Another computation at $5$ then shows this is an integral basis and one is done.

**Warning!** Not all fields have an integral basis given by powers of a single element (although this is true in degrees $1$ and $2$). Such fields are called monogenic, and, by certain measures, are rare. Determining if a field is monogenic or not can be quite non-trivial.

Of course, in your particular case, you can easily recognize the field from the fact that it is abelian and has discriminant $5^3$. Namely, it must be the field of fifth roots of unity. After you make this guess, you can compute that

$$\zeta = -\frac{3}{11} \beta^3 + \frac{4}{11} \beta^2 - \frac{9}{11} \beta - \frac{14}{11} = -1 + 0 \cdot \beta + 2 \cdot \beta^2  - 3 \cdot \gamma$$

does indeed satisfy $\zeta^5 = 1$.

Comment: Gordon. Do you have a proof of the correct formulation?. I also thought that was what the autor had in mind but I couln't work out the proof.

Comment: It's an easy lemma about lattices. Suppose that $\Lambda$ and $ \Lambda'$ are free $\mathbf{Z}$ modules of rank $n$, and $\Lambda \subset \Lambda'$ has index divisible by $p$. Consider the map: $\Lambda/p \Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda'/p \Lambda'$. The index assumption implies that this is not surjective, and so comparing ranks it is not injective either. Hence there is a $\lambda \in \Lambda$ such that $\lambda/p \not\in \Lambda$ but $\lambda/p \in \Lambda'$. Now apply this with $\Lambda' = \mathcal{O}_K$ and $\Lambda = \mathbf{Z}[\beta_i]$.

Comment: Your answer gives a consistent replacement of the theorem (and a very nice proof too) but covers but only half of the question. Indeed , the change of coordinates in going form the first basis into the one where the element $\beta_i$ is replaced by $\gamma$ is expressed by the following matrix (see next comment)

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\0&1&0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\\vdots&\cdots&\ddots&0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\0&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0\\\frac{1}{p}\lambda_1&\cdots&\frac{1}{p}\lambda_{i-2}&\frac{1}{p}\lambda_{i-1}&\frac{1}{p}\lambda_i&\frac{1}{p}\lambda_{i+1}&\cdots&\cdots&\frac{1}{p}\lambda_n\\0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0&1&0&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots&\cdots&\vdots\\\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\ddots&0\\0&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This matrix has determinant $\frac{\lambda_i}{p}$ so that the discriminant is multiplied with the square of this number. This makes that the factor $p^2$ disapears from the discriminant but a factor $\lambda_i^2$ appears.

Comment: Conveniently you chose an element associated with a value where $\lambda_i = 1$ (while, in my example I chose on purpose one where $\lambda_i = 3$, making a factor $9$ appear in the discriminant). Up to now there is no guarantee that one of the coefficients $\lambda_i$ equals one so we still are not nearer to an integral basis. The only thing we know is that the field discriminant divides both discriminants thus also their $\gcd$.

Comment: I was a little sloppy; it's fairly clear how to ensure that $\lambda_i = 1$ for some $i$, I added a clarifying remark.

Comment: The answer is now complete and correct. Thanks, we have now a valid algorithm for constructing integral bases..